# Why CPU DDR Memory Controller Has 2 Clock Outputs?

Tags: clock, cpu, nxp, dram

I'm trying to understand the ddr structure for the iMX6 Rex Module .
The cpu used is the MCIMX6Q5EYM10AC model from the NXP i.mx quad series.

[MCIMX6Q5EYM10AC Datasheet](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/IMX6DQCEC.pdf)

[iMX6 Rex Module Shematics](https://www.imx6rex.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/iMX6-Rex-Module-Schematic.pdf)

A configuration was made using 4 x16 ddr3 Dram, with a total of 64 word lengths. So far everything is great. Why are there 2 (DRAM_SDCLK_0, DRAM_SDCLK_1 ) clock outputs?Does it matter from which clock source we feed the ddr chips?

[image]
[image]